# Should we decouple Application Layer from HTTP?

Tags: model-view-controller, domain-driven-design

Assuming you follow DDD and you have your Domain, Application and Presentation (Controller) Layers, should the Application Layer be completely decoupled from knowing anything about HTTP requests and all the other things that go with it such as cookies, sessions, etc.

To illustrate, say our `CommentingService` in Application Layer needs a value from a cookie named `guestId`. Should this value be passed in as a parameter to our service or can we pass the whole `Request` (`HttpContext`) object and let our service extract it from there.

Commons sense tells me that if I would want to reuse this Application Layer somewhere else I would want it to be decoupled from web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Services

Yes, you will want to `decouple` your application layer from any web concerns.
`Application layer` is responsible for managing your domain objects like aggregates, repositories etc (orchestration).

Mostly you will go with next layer providing Rest Api functionality.

If you decompose it like that, you could use your API with CLI, Rest, Soap or whatever your business want you to provide.

#### Cross-cutting concerns

You will want to implement `cross-cutting concerns` in your `application layer`, because you do not want to reinvent wheel for every outside layer.
For example: security, caching, transaction managing logging. 
It doesn't provide you with `business capabilities`, so you do not implement them in `domain layer`, but you can implement it in your `application layer`.